# Why doesn't this bash/diff command work through Neovim?

Tags: bash, vim, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

I am using WSL bash (Ubuntu distribution).

From Windows command line, this works as expected:

`bash -c 'diff test.txt -'`

However when running the following through Neovim:

`:w !bash -c 'diff % -'`

This is the erroneous output:

```
diff: -: Illegal seek

shell returned 2
```

Why is this illegal seek error happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Update: `:w !bash -c "cat - | diff % -"` works.